# Git - submodule fatal clone (libpd)

Tags: git, libpd

I am trying to install the Pure Data for Android library using git, but I keep getting the same error.

I create a new directory in which I clone the repository, and run `cd pd-for-android` to move to the repository folder.
After I run `git submodule update --init --recursive`, I get the following:

```
fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/libpd/libpd.git' into submodule path 
/Users/myUserName/Desktop/pd-android-test/pd-for-android/PdCore/jni/libpd' failed.
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo [libpd/pd-for-android](https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android) (Pure Data for Android library) has a [`.gitmodules`](https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android/blob/master/.gitmodules) which uses the git URL `git://github.com/libpd/libpd.git`

If, as in this issue, this is related to the git protocol, try first:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git config url."https://".insteadOf git://
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Or try a more global rule (limited to that repo), with a `git clone --recursive` (that will clone the main repo and the submodules immediately, saving you one step)

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/libpd/".insteadOf git://github.com/libpd/
```

That way, you do not deactivate the use of `git://` for *all* repos.

Comment: though this will prevent you from ever using the `git://` protocol (until you revert that change)

Comment: @umläute good point. I have limited that rule to that one local repo

Comment: Now I get `fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/nettoyeurny/opensl_stream.git' into submodule path '/Users/me/Desktop/pd_andro/pd-for-android/PdCore/jni/libpd/jni/opensl_stream' failed
Failed to clone 'jni/opensl_stream'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/Users/me/Desktop/pd_andro/pd-for-android/PdCore/jni/libpd/pure-data'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.code.sf.net:
git.code.sf.net[0: 216.34.181.155]: errno=Operation timed out`

Comment: @slwjc As long as you see `git://`, that means the config "`insteadOf`" was not apply. What `git config` command did you type?

Comment: I tried both `git config url."https://".insteadOf git://` and `git config --global url."https://github.com/libpd/".insteadOf git://github.com/libpd/`

Comment: @slwjc How about `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` (for testing). Then clone again with `git clone --recursive`